# Ajax passing null value to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a dropdown that has a list of ID's in it. The customer will select one and it will reflect a price total on the page. Im creating an ajax call that will update the total when a different ID is pulled from the Dropdown.

```
$("#BrandId").on('focus', function () {
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    previous = this.value;
}).change(function () {
    alert("Previous: " +previous);
    sel = this.value;
    alert("Selected: " +sel);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBrandCost", "Shocks")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ idp: previous, id: sel }),
        dataType: "json",
        aysnc: false,
        success: function (data1) {
            alert(data1);
                //ShockTotal = $("#ShockTotal").html();
                //ShockTotal = ShockTotal / 1;
                ////ShockTotal = ShockTotal - data1;
                //$("#ShockTotal").html(data1);

        }
    });
});
```

The alerts are working perfectly but the ajax isnt passing those ID's into the controller, the controller is just receiving nulls.

```
 public decimal GetBrandCost(string idp, string id)
    {
        decimal costp = 0;
        decimal cost = 0;
        if (id == "" || id == null || idp == "" || idp == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        ShockBrand brandp = db.ShockBrands.Find(idp);
        costp = brandp.Cost;
        ShockBrand brand = db.ShockBrands.Find(id);
        cost = brand.Cost;
        cost = cost - costp;
        return cost;
    }
```

Since they are null I am hitting my if statement and just returning zero inside the success. Most of the things I read were to add the content type but that didnt seem to help in my case, Im sure it is something little.

Comment: why not just: ``data: { idp: previous, id: sel }``  there is no need to do stringify

Comment: When I do that and go into my controller to debug, it passes in the same value for idp and id equal to the value assigned for the change function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From browser console, this

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'http://google.com',
        data: JSON.stringify({ idp: 1, id: 2 }),
        dataType: "json",
        aysnc: false,
        success: function (data1) {
           console.log(data1)

        }
    });
```

returns request to `http://google.com/?{%22idp%22:1,%22id%22:2}&_=1440696352799`, which is incorrect

and without stringify

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "get",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'http://google.com',
        data: { idp: 1, id: 2 },
        dataType: "json",
        aysnc: false,
        success: function (data1) {
           console.log(data1)

        }
    });
```

returns `http://google.com/?idp=1&id=2&_=1440696381239` (see Network tab)

So don't use JSON.stringify

Why it's gonna work - your asp.net controller action receives simple typed parameters (string, numbers, etc) and jquery is fairly enought smart to determine what are going to send, if it was object inside object it will send it as POST data for POST, and string represenation of object for GET (you have GET request, but for purpose of knowledge, just stick with 2 types of data that can be send, *params* & *data*) So when jquery configures url, asp.net understands conventions, and matches request to approciated action

But Don't believe me, check it yourself

chrome dev console is your friend

Comment: I guess now my problem is that is the ajax call is passing in the same value for idp and id even though the alerts are showing the correct values.

Comment: check network tab, if they are really equal, then there is a mistake in your js code, be sure to have same data type, string to string, int to int, etc.

Comment: It took me a little bit to realize but I recognized that my focus function would always update my previous to the new selected value. So I took the value of the previous of the focus and put it to a scapegoat value when I change, so the js wouldnt over write the previous.

Comment: @failsatheals if you like the answer, upvote it, so that newcomers will easily find answer

Comment: If you don't stringify (and there is no need to), you should remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it like

```
var dataReq={ idp: previous, id: sel };
data: dataReq
```

And no need to use dataType and contentType.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8
and
dataType: "json"
it worked for me. Otherwise, I was always getting value = null in the controller action.
My code for calling ajax with data is now:

```
 $(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Case/AjaxMethodForUpdate",
        data: {typ: $('#typeID').val()},
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```